# Handel multi choice or selected radioButton in recyclerView inside another recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have activity contain parent multirow recyclerView have tow attribute in each element (question, answers in child recyclerView ) like this

[this show what I mean](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6CMo.png)

my problem here, How can I handle the choice of every child recycler until not removed or duplicated when user scroll recyclerView

that's my onBindViewHolder code:

```
 @Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

    // get objects
    final FollowQuestionModel item = data.get(position);
    if (item != null) {

        switch (item.getType()) {

            case SINGLE_TYPE:

                ((SingleViewHolder) holder).tvSingleChoice.setText(item.getSingleChoiceModel().get(position).getQuestion());

                ((SingleViewHolder) holder).rvSingleChoice.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context , 2));
                SingleAnswersElementAdapter singleAdapter = new SingleAnswersElementAdapter(context, item.getSingleChoiceModel().get(position).getAnswers()
                        , R.layout.item_single_choice_element);
                ((SingleViewHolder) holder).rvSingleChoice.setAdapter(singleAdapter);

                break;

            case MULTI_TYPE:

                ((MultiViewHolder) holder).tvMultiChoice.setText(item.getSingleChoiceModel().get(position).getQuestion());

                ((MultiViewHolder) holder).rvMulitChoice.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context , 2));
                MultiAnswersElementAdapter multiAdapter = new MultiAnswersElementAdapter(context, item.getMultiChoiceModel().get(position).getAnswers()
                        , R.layout.item_multi_choice_element);
                ((MultiViewHolder) holder).rvMulitChoice.setAdapter(multiAdapter);

                break;

            case TEXT_TYPE:

                ((TextViewHolder) holder).tvTextQuestion.setText(item.getTextChoiceModel().get(position).getQuestion().get(position).getQuestion());

                break;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks

Comment: more explanation please.

Comment: are you see the picture attached to the question?

Comment: Sure.. but i didn't get it, what you need excatly